# Javascript image and href swap on image gallery

Tags: javascript, href, swap, image-gallery

I have an image gallery on my site that has one large display image with caption and 3 smaller thumbnail images below. Right now, I have a javascript that enables the display image and caption to be swapped out when you click on the different thumbnails. My end goal, and what I am having difficulty with is to have each of the large display images link to a different video.

My faulty javascript which works for display image and caption swapping but not link swapping is this:

```
function showPic (whichpic) { 
    if (document.getElementById) { 
        document.getElementById('placeholder').src = whichpic.href;
        document.getElementById('link').href = whichpic.video;
        if (whichpic.title) { 
            document.getElementById('desc').childNodes[0].nodeValue = whichpic.title; 
        } else { 
            document.getElementById('desc').childNodes[0].nodeValue = whichpic.childNodes[0].nodeValue; 
        } 
        return false; 
    } else { 
        return true; 
    } 

}
```

The HTML is as follows:

```
<div id="itemart">
    <script src="js/showPic.js" type="text/javascript" language="javascript"></script>
        <a id="link" href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SgARL8aHl8Q" title="Video Title" class="lightbox" data-height="480"><img id="placeholder" src="img/Coke_01_AnimationStoryboard.png" alt="Coca-Cola Plastic Recycling Animation." /></a>
        <p id="desc">Display image 01 caption.</p>
        <ul class="thumbnails">
            <li><a onclick="return showPic(this)" href="img/Coke_01_AnimationStoryboard.png" title="Coca-Cola plastic recycling animation storyboard." video="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SgARL8aHl8Q"><img name="itemarttthumbnail1" width=50 height=50 src="img/thumbs/Coke_01_thumb01.png" alt="Cola-Cola Plastic Recycling Animation" style="background-color: #00FF66" /></a></li>
            <li><a onclick="return showPic(this)" href="img/Coke_02_AnimationStoryboard.png" title="Coca-Cola aluminum recycling animation storyboard." video="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wq2GbbMJ20Q"><img name="itemarttthumbnail2" width=50 height=50 src="img/thumbs/Coke_02_thumb02.png" alt="Coca-Cola Aluminum Recycling Animation" style="background-color: #00FF66" /></a></li>
            <li><a onclick="return showPic(this)" href="img/Coke_03_AnimationStoryboard.png" title="Coca-Cola glass recycling animation storyboard." video="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qU5TOA3kWPs"><img name="itemarttthumbnail3" width=50 height=50 src="img/thumbs/Coke_03_thumb03.png" alt="Coca-Cola Glass Recycling Animation" style="background-color: #00FF66" /></a></li>
        </ul>

</div>
```

I am not very adept with Javascript so I may be missing something very obvious. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I only had a quick glance over your code but try changing this line:

```
document.getElementById('link').href = whichpic.video;
```

with this:

```
document.getElementById('link').href = whichpic.getAttribute('video');
```

EDIT 2::

Try passing the video url as an argument to the script.

```
onclick="return showPic(this,'theUrlStringfromTheVideoTag');
```

And then alter the following lines in the js.

```
function showPic (whichpic,url) { 
document.getElementById('link').href =url;
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but no luck. The display (or "placeholder") image href doesn't switch out so it keeps playing the same video for each of the different display images that pop up. Thanks again though.

Comment: @bhrycyk Different approach you can try

Comment: Thanks again for all of your work but I think I screwed up in my initial question by adding by adding generic youtube addresses in my markup language and I didn't consider the repercussions of that. I apologize for that assumption. I added all of my actual markup language to avoid any further confusion created by me.

Comment: ...but still no luck. I just can't seem to get the "video" ID content to populate the "link" ID href.

Comment: I still couldn't get this code to work so I simply had change my approach to something that wasn't as dynamic. It's not ideal but it works.